# XCode - Display Vietnamese : Unicode problem

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I need to display Vietnamese in my APP. But now, i cannot show the words in correct format. For example, the word "&#code" i cannot convert it to Vietnamese, it just display "&#code;".

Does anyone can help me how to handle the word in unicode ?

Thanks a lot!

Tisa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write the unicode string inside `@"..."` without quoting. Strictly speaking, that's non-portable, but as long as you use it for just for Objective-C, it should be OK.  It should work on a modern XCode toolchain.

In general, you need to understand that `&#...` is a way to quote unicode character in HTML, not in a C-string. In C, if you want to be most portable, you need to use `\x` escapes. Some newer compilers accept `\u...` and `\U...` for unicodes.

Comment: thanks for your answer. But can you tell me how to convert the html unicode &#... to \u... using vb.net or xcode?

Comment: Do you really want to get `\u`-encoded form of the string? Or do you want a unicode string from `&#...`?